# Is there a specific Ubuntu Touch rom for xperia ion?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I just want to know if there is any specific rom online for Sony Xperia ion.

Are there installation instruction too?

Comment: Thank you for the answer,

I tried the link you had given me it is not working i afraid.
I think my Xperia ION is having a driver named aoba but i could't find that on the list also when i tried to install it

error log was,

getprop("ro.product.device")=="nozomi", status 7 and installation aborted 

I used CWM based Recovery 6.0.2.8

Please let me know if something

Answer (score -1):

I think you could be first to install and share your experience:
[**Ubuntu Touch Install Getting Started**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)
[**Installing Ubuntu for Devices**](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

Comment: the new instructions can be found [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)